# Find every $n$: $n^2 + 340 = m^2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

Let $n$, $m \in N$.

The problem asks to find every natural number $ n $ such that:

$ n^2 + 340 = m^2 $

I tried to solve the equation like this:

$ n^2 - m^2 = 340 $

$ (n + m)(n - m) = 2^2 * 5 * 17 $

I listed all possible pairs of dividers of 340:

$(1, 340), (2, 170), (4, 85), (5, 68), (10, 34), (20, 17)$

I set up six linear systems; only two gave me integers.

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
m+n=170 \\
m-n=2   \\
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
$m = 86, n = 84$

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
m+n=34 \\ 
m-n=10 \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

$m = 22, n = 12$

I posted this problem because I don't have the solution. Did I make any mistake? Could the problem be solved in a quicker way?

Thanks.

Comment: One thing to bear in mind is that $n-m$ and $n+m$ must both be the same parity.  So they must both be even.

Comment: "I posted this problem because I don't have the solution."  So what *was* the solution.  That's the way I'd do it.  If you didn't make an arithmetic error I don't see why you wouldn't have gotten the answer

Comment: Yes, I mean, I don't have the solution from the people who have invented the problem. But from the answers now I understand that the way I solved the problem is right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the way you did it is the best way.

A worse way would be that if we let $m = n + k$ then $n^2 + 2nk + k^2 = m^2$ so $2nk + k^2 = 340$.  Clearly $k$ is even so if $k=2k'$ then $nk' + k'^2 = 85$.  And $k'(n+k') = 85$ so for $k' =1....\sqrt{85};k|85=5*17$ or in other words for $k'=1, 5$  we get $n=84,12$  and $k=2,10$ so $(m,n) = (86,84)$ or $(22, 10)$.

Hmm... I guess that wasn't *that* much worse.  In essence it was basically the same thing.

Still I prefer your way which would have been for first choice.

Answer (score 3):

The only shortcut is to notice both factors need to be even, so you must put one $2$ in each factor. That reduces the problem to the factorisation of $85$. There are just two solutions because it's semiprime.